# Javascript Polymer: how to break/stop function

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've created an HTML webpage with some polymer in it. Now, I'm looking for a way to stop my polymer function.

My code is the following:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'serverenelement-app',
  leegmaken: function() {

if(this.shadowRoot.getElementById("regel1").value.length != 0 && this.shadowRoot.getElementById("radio1").checked == true) {
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById("regel1").value = "";
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById("radio1").checked = false;
}
else if (this.shadowRoot.getElementById("regel1").value.length == 0 && this.shadowRoot.getElementById("radio1").checked == true) {
  alert("Kan niet bevestigd worden.\nControlleer of de status en het tafelnummer beide zijn ingevuld.");
  break leegmaken;
  }
else if (this.shadowRoot.getElementById("regel1").value.length != 0 && this.shadowRoot.getElementById("radio1").checked == false) {
  alert("Kan niet bevestigd worden.\nControlleer of de status en het tafelnummer beide zijn ingevuld.");
  break leegmaken;
  }
}
  });
```

I've tried breaking it like this. I found this method on another forum, yet this doesn't work. 
My console says the following:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'leegmaken'

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem of mine? I couldn't find a solution, which is why I'm asking here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `break leegmaken;` to `return;`

Comment: Thanks bro! Love you ♥

Comment: No problem. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp for how return works.